# How can I index SVG icons for my project?

Tags: javascript, svg, svelte

I have an Electron/Svelte project where I place `index.js` files in all my folders for proper structure and indexing. A typical `index.js` includes code similar to this:

```
export { default as [FILENAME] } from './FILENAME.svelte'
```

My main project structure includes to main folders: `assets` (where the icons are located) and `src` where I want to load them.

I am trying to export icons from the `assets` folder using code like this:

```
export { default as ArrowUp } from './icons/arrow_up.svg'
```

But when I import the icon in Svelte, I get the following error:

> [!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
> assets/icons/Arrow_Up.svg (1:0)
> 1: <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" ...

I believe I need a different way to export the references from the folder. I tried using a different approach where I export a URL reference like so:

```
export const arrow = new URL('../../assets/icons/arrow_up.svg', import.meta.url).href
```

Which seems to work fine. Can someone explain to me why my first approach fails, but the second one works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is that an `svg` is not JavaScript. Your solution is a hacky way of creating a link to the svg which JS recognizes as a string, so it works. I'm pretty sure you'd need `index.js` to be a `jsx` file if you're wanting to just import the svg directly. Or what you could do is convert your svg files into jsx components and import them that way like:

```
const ArrowIcon = () => (
   <svg></svg>
);

export default ArrowIcon;
```